# Swing data binding frameworks

Tags: java, swing, data-binding

Almost the same question has been asked a [year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510655/jgoodies-binding-vs-jsr-295), but the there has been some new development in this area.

Selecting a (data binding) framework for swing application seems to be quite difficult. JSR-295 is abandoned, many swing frameworks which provide binding are work-in-progress, abandoned or too heavy for my quite simple app. JGoodies Swing suite is expensive, but luckily its libraries are free.

Has anyone any real-world experience of new [UFaceKit](http://code.google.com/p/uface/). It looks promising, but quite immature. I am particularly interested in Swing implementation and documentation. Any insight on UFaceKits development schedule would be appreciated, because I can hold by framework choice for a while. Requirements are not anything fancy, just working binding with a nice API.

I also found [Mogwai dataBinding](http://mogwai.sourceforge.net/?Welcome:DataBinding), but it seems quite incomplete and requires manual synchronization activation, which makes it useless compared to coarse grained synchronization [easily written by hand](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

Incomplete frameworks include at least [Spring RCP](http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/index.html) and many JSR-296 forks.

So, is the JGoodies data binding really the only realistic choice? Or are there any other viable solutions available?

---

*Edit:*
This question seems to rank quite high in google and the accepted answer reflects the time question was originally asked. Anyone who seeks to build new swing application that uses databinding should check all the answers, they have information about latest progress in this area.

Comment: if you like groovy then take a look at griffon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BBB](http://kenai.com/projects/betterbeansbinding/pages/Home) (pretty much the official fork of JSR 295) works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look of it.

Answer (score 3):

The Beanfabrics framework contains some sort of data binding. In fact it is an implementation of the Presentation Model pattern: http://code.google.com/p/beanfabrics/

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a library that has support for Swing data binding using Views, Binders and ControlAccessors for Swing Components.

See http://www.jdal.org/doc/swing/jdal-swing-binding.php

Answer (score 0):

This project also has a data binding to forms that's easy to use, I'm created this project 2 years ago and it's growing from my ideas and some collaborators since that.

https://github.com/MarkyVasconcelos/Towel

Answer (score 0):

We are going to use now [Eclipse WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), and I think it should go well

See [Swing Data Binding Example](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/features/swing/data_binding/example.html) at http://code.google.com/javadevtools/

It is uses beansbinding-1.2.1.jar, that is jdesktop.org project. If it is related to JSR-295, I don't know (please edit)

Answer (score 0):

Melasse project can glue UI and beans togather w/o creating class: `Binder.bind(/* source, target, options */)`.

e.g. To enable an action/button only when textfield is not empty: https://github.com/cchantep/melasse/blob/master/README.md#bind-buttonaction-to-provided-value .