# Java swing - how to bind my fields to a module

Tags: java, swing, data-binding, bind

I am writing in java swing and I am wondering if there is a better(shorter) way to bind my object to the gui forms.

I will describe this need for an example -  Zero Button :
Lets say I want on the GUI to have a number field and a button that puts zero in it. That's it.
I have a gui - form and java class . and a module class that holds all the data and does some logic.

What I will usually  do (and I think its awful) is :

1. Create the gui elements.
2. On the module create a list that holds all the listeners to the change in the specific field.
3. On the gui - at the beginnig add a listner to the module [send an anonymous class (value changed)]
4. On the Module - in the setter - iterate the listeners list and notify all.
5. On the gui - my listener changes the TextField to zero.

This whole process just to put a zero in the field next to it :-0).
and now for each field...
This is waaaay to long for me .
(Sometimes i just want to set the module to zero and than set the gui text to zero in two simple lines of code)
Is this the best practice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Best practise* to me is to choose a databinding framework and use it consequently. Databinding is exactly what you want - a synchronization between model (sic!) and UI

[Here's a Q/A page on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400998/swing-data-binding-frameworks) that includes a lot of links to databinding frameworks for Java Swing applications.

Comment: is there any real alternative but JGoodies as far as binding frameworks for java + swing go?

Comment: @Jens Schauder - can't answer that question, I usually use SWT ;)  - That's why I gave to pointer to the other question instead of just recommending something

Comment: Thanks. I usually do the longer writing process just cause it is easier to debug. Frameworks tend to be harder when the there are troubles. I will surely check  your recommendation.

Comment: @Jens Schauder: there is BBB (Better Beans Binding). Don't you like JGoodies Binding?

Comment: @jfpoilpret I do like JGoodies but I'm always interested in alternatives. I knew about a JSR (295?) which is dead afaik. I'll have a look at BBB.

Comment: Just looked at BBB and it looks just as dead as JSR295

Comment: Really? Maybe that's due to the changes from java.net (due to Oracle). I don't know. BBB is actually a fork of JSR-295. The main issue I have with it is the lack of documentation (couldn't find any good tutorial to get started). On the other side, my pet peeve with JGoodies is the lack of type-safety, that's why I started rewriting it with a lot of generics (my work can be seen on guts project subversion). JGoodies is very well documented and easy to get started with.